# Is it possible to generate artificial gravity without using a centrifuge system?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, mass-energy, centrifugal-force

I was doing research on General Relativity and Einstein's field equations and pondered on a device using that would generate [artificial gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity) without the use of rotational forces. I wondered since energy and mass are basically the same things (as denoted in $E=mc^2$), then couldn't it be $m=E/c^2$, or an equation similar to that one? (I'm sure my sources and my own math were off a bit, hence me asking the minds on here.)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338744/123208

Answer (score 5):

Mass and energy are equivalent, and affect gravity in the same way, so yes, you could produce gravity by putting enough energy on your spaceship. But then you're not producing "artificial" gravity, it would be real gravity, and that energy would have inertia just the same as the equivalent mass would. In fact matter is probably the most compact form of energy. Basically you're looking at having a spaceship big enough to have a significant gravitational field of its own. This is not very practical.

A far better way to produce artificial gravity is to accelerate. While your spaceship is accelerating, all of its passengers feel a force pushing them towards the back of the spaceship. This force is indistinguishable from gravity (it's called the "equivalence principle"). Of course this would require a lot of fuel or some form of external propulsion.

Comment: I see. I was asking this question to also see if it was possible to fold space using energy, primarily in the form of a high-frequency, oscillating electromagnetic field, such as that in an Alcubierre Drive. (Don't kill me for dreaming yet, I'm only exploring the plausibility before the possibility.) The reason why I was wondering if that would work was that gravity distorts spacetime, and I was thinking if energy can change forms, what if we use EM energy to manipulate spacetime? (I'm having a hard time explaining this, so I hope it makes some sense.

Comment: Well, every EM field does warp spacetime by virtue of having energy, but the amount of warping is incredibly small unless you get into implausibly strong fields ("convert the mass of an astroid into energy" strengths). The Alcubierre drive is different, it's a particular way of warping spacetime that as I understand it requires negative energy to work. I believe everything inside the warp bubble would accelerate together in the same way (so basically the contents of the warp bubble would be in free fall and would not feel the effects of the spacetime warp)..

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that the energy content of something strengthens its gravitation, this is just another way of saying that a more energetic object weighs slightly more than the same object in a lower energy condition. As such, these facts don't furnish us with any tools with which to create "artificial gravity".